# Selecting a subset of rows that meet a TRUE condition

Tags: r, plot, subset, logical-operators

I have a dataframe `df`. I want to plot two variables, `a` and `t`, against each other, but using only certain rows. The rows I want to use must meet three conditions:

1. A third variable, `s`, must be >= 0.9
2. The third variable `s` must also be <=1.1
3. I only want the rows that have met the condition of having no NAs/missing values for `a`, `t`, and `s`.

I have created a logical vector that returns values of `TRUE` and `FALSE` to meet this third condition, but I don't know how to work this into my code.

Here is my code so far, which I believe produces the desired result with the exception of the third condition:

```
plot(log(df$t)[df$s >= .9 & df$s <= 1.1],log(df$a)[df$s >= .9 & df$s <= 1.1])
```

What can I add to it to satisfy the third condition?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data=df[df$s >= 0.9 & df$s <= 1.1 & !is.na(df$a) & !is.na(df$s) & !is.na(df$t),])
p + geom_point(aes(x = t, y = a))
```

Comment: I follow the logic of this, but I return the error message: >Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (439): x, y

Comment: Hm, it seems like it's trying to plot the unfiltered t & a. You didn't change the code, right?

Comment: I didn't. I was able to create a subset of the original dataset to eliminate the rows with undesired NAs, and then plotted with that one. Less neat, but I think it did work.

Comment: Feel free to edit my or any other answer or post your own solution btw